# GridView miss placing icons and scrolls Infinitily

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, grid, infinite

The scrolling of gridview goes **infinitely up and we cant get back to grids anymore**.
And also sometimes adds **null grids** on scrolling.

what might be the reason? How can i solve it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

auto_fit  = -1
Display as many columns as possible to fill the available space.

have you used this?
this brings that sort of problem!

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android:numColumns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android%3anumColumns)

Comment: Use the android:numColumns="4" in your GridView widget

Comment: where should i give this auto_fit = -1